# Synapse spark pool : have a pool of idle nodes to execute the code after invocation

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

Do we have Databricks cluster pools like option in Synapse spark pool as well? wherein i can have idle nodes to execute the code soon after notebook invocation.

[image]

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

The automatic pause feature in Azure Synapse Analytics can be used to optimize costs by releasing resources during idle periods.

You can specify the idle time duration in minutes before resources are automatically released. Also, you can adjust this setting after creating the pool; any active sessions will need to be restarted. It is important to note that the automatic pause feature operates independently of the autoscale feature. Therefore, resources can be paused regardless of whether autoscaling is enabled or disabled.

Below are the steps to enable automatic pause:

**Step 1:** Select Azure Synapse Analytics.

**Step 2:** Select the Apache Spark pools tab and select the Spark pool that you want to configure.

[image]

**Step 3:** Under Settings, select Automatic pause & set the Number of minutes idle to the number of minutes that you want the Spark pool to be idle before it is paused.

[image]

**Step 4:** Apply and save changes.

**Reference:** [Automatic pause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-pool-configurations#automatic-pause)

Comment: Its not about Pause or auto termination feature which i was looking at. I was checking on idle nodes configuration in synapse, so that when a request comes system should pick up execution within fraction of seconds(databricks says 40 secs)

Comment: @ravibhat let me update the solution for you regarding the idle nodes configuration in synapse